# Can I safely clean up the .emacs-mail-crash-box and how not to store mail localy?

Tags: gnus, email

I've just discovered that this file (written by Gnus) is almost 50 MB big.  I don't need my mail archived locally.  How can I tell Gnus not to save it there? (Or, maybe, if possible, for only a very short time, like a week or so).

I've looked here: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Mail-Source-Customization.html but this doesn't answer the question.  From this I can't understand what exactly is stored in this file, and whether it's ok to delete it.

PS. I also don't want to store outgoing mail there, in case it's stored there.  I.e. I don't want Gnus to ever store any mail on my computer for longer than a few days (but would chose not to store it at all if I had to).

---

Here's an update: I tried, at first, to truncate the file (i.e. `echo '' > ./.emacs-mail-crash-box`), which caused some bizarre problems, and Gnus wouldn't connect. But completely removing this file let Gnus connect to my GMail account. I didn't investigate the problem though. The symptoms were these: after starting Gnus it would hang for a while, and when interrupted it would give a message related to missing `'*nnir-something*` but grepping the source code I couldn't find where the message was coming from.

Comment: The crashbox file should be processed and deleted when you start up Gnus. I believe it is only created to handle cases where Gnus crashes or otherwise terminates abnormally. There is also an 'incoming' file - and N of those are kept (where N is set by `mail-source-delete-incoming`).

Comment: @verdammelt could you tell if "incorrectly terminated" SSL connection will count as a crash? My Emacs typically stays open for months but the connection dies several times during the day.

Comment: sorry but I don't know exactly under what circumstances the crash box file is left behind.